# How to create a sticky deformer in maya

Tags: python, api, maya

So I want to create a sticky deformer in Maya using python or python API, but I can't seem to figure out where to start from. I want to be able to select a vertex and create a softMod deformer that will follow the geom preferably without having to create a hair follicle. I've tried searching around the net for a few days and I can't seem to find anything to point me in the right direction. My knowledge of Maya Python API isn't great, I know I may be diving into the deep end but it's out of desperation.

I'm hoping someone could help me or at least point me in the direction I should research on, even if it's to learn Maya's API(I've checked out Chad Vernon's tuts and they kind of went over my head)

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried the either [sculpt deformers](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-8A7188B9-34C1-48B8-B690-5CB0EA36932D-htm.html) or [clusters](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-CharacterAnimation/files/GUID-B7C96FEA-C415-4927-8E02-396F0E837DE2-htm.html)? It's hard to know exactly what to suggest without more info

Comment: Sculpt deformer usage is limited and it can't be keyed. I'm not looking to make specific shapes, this is more for clean up purposes after running some simulations. Clusters again has the same issue as softmods, after creating them, they don't follow the geometry they're created on. I need to figure out a way to create a softmod that follows along with the geometry it's created on so that I can tweak it while looking at the geometry rather than tweaking it from wherever it is and trying to figure out when it's far away from the geom.

Comment: When you say "follow the geom" do you mean follow the animating verts? or follow the object transform?

Comment: follow the selected animated vert.